# Recompile Python bytecode instructions

Tags: python, python-3.x, bytecode, bytecode-manipulation

Suppose I have a `speak` function:

```
def speak():
    print("moo")
```

I can disassemble it as one usually does, with [`dis.dis`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html#dis.dis):

```
>>> dis.dis(speak)
  2           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (print)
              3 LOAD_CONST               1 ('moo')
              6 CALL_FUNCTION            1 (1 positional, 0 keyword pair)
              9 POP_TOP
             10 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             13 RETURN_VALUE
```

But I want to destruct the code object associated with the `speak` function into a sequence of instructions, and then compile these back.
With the help of [`dis.Bytecode`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html#dis.Bytecode), I can get a sequence of [`dis.Instruction`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html#dis.Instruction)s that represents the code object:

```
>>> bytecode = dis.Bytecode(speak)
>>> for instruction in bytecode:
...     print(instruction)
... 
Instruction(opname='LOAD_GLOBAL', opcode=116, arg=0, argval='print', argrepr='print', offset=0, starts_line=2, is_jump_target=False)
Instruction(opname='LOAD_CONST', opcode=100, arg=1, argval='moo', argrepr="'moo'", offset=3, starts_line=None, is_jump_target=False)
Instruction(opname='CALL_FUNCTION', opcode=131, arg=1, argval=1, argrepr='1 positional, 0 keyword pair', offset=6, starts_line=None, is_jump_target=False)
Instruction(opname='POP_TOP', opcode=1, arg=None, argval=None, argrepr='', offset=9, starts_line=None, is_jump_target=False)
Instruction(opname='LOAD_CONST', opcode=100, arg=0, argval=None, argrepr='None', offset=10, starts_line=None, is_jump_target=False)
Instruction(opname='RETURN_VALUE', opcode=83, arg=None, argval=None, argrepr='', offset=13, starts_line=None, is_jump_target=False)
```

Is there a straightforward way to compile these `Instruction` objects into the original code object?

For instance, I'm looking for a `compile_back` function that would take a sequence of instructions and output an `exec`utable code object:

```
>>> code_object = compile_back(dis.get_instructions(speak))
>>> exec(code_object)
moo
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sequence of `Instruction` objects from `dis.Bytecode` is not enough to reconstruct a code object. A code object isn't just a sequence of instructions; it includes plenty of other data, like the argument count, the size of the evaluation stack, flags indicating various properties, etc. Most of these things are (briefly) described in a [table](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#types-and-members) in the `inspect` module docs, but there's even some ["scratch space"](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0523/#expanding-pycodeobject) not accessible through ordinary means.

`Instruction` objects would be enough to recover a lot of a code object's information, but not all. With some dangerous assumptions, you might be able to get something that usually works, but it'd be better to keep more of the information from the original code object in the first place.

In any case, there's no *straightforward* way.